# how to create a .sql file using the following script

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE `downloads` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` text NOT NULL ,
  `file` text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

CREATE TABLE `coupons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) TYPE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```

Comment: What do you mean about 'create a .sql file'?

Answer (score 0):

@Juno: Do you mean you want to have a .sql file which would contain these two tables.

If yes, Using phpmyadmin then you may first create a DB and execute your SQL query. Then you can export the DB and you will get the ".sql" file as per your requirement.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open any editor and paste your code.

   Remove TYPE = MyISAM... to ENGINE=MyISAM...

   Import your sql file in your database.

**Note:** set your database if you have not selected it.

```
CREATE TABLE `downloads` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `title` text NOT NULL ,
  `file` text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;

CREATE TABLE `coupons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `code` varchar(255) NOT NULL ,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=10 ;
```